# How to format name of students when calculating avg of marks in C

Tags: c

This is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){

  int i, j;
  float average;

  int grades[5][2] = {
                 {40, 45},
                 {37, 40},
                 {43, 49},
                 {33, 39},
                 {46, 45}
                 };

  printf("Let's calculate the average of the marks obtained by the students "
         "in the two subjects.\n\n");

  for(j = 0; j < 5; j++){
    average = 0;
    for(i = 0; i < 2; i++){
      average += grades[j][i];
    }
    printf("The average mark scored by the student %d is -> %.2f out of 50 \n", j, average/2);
  }
}
```

It gives the output as: 'The average mark scored by student (index of j) is'

How would I go about making it output names of different students? example - 'The average mark scored by student John is'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have an array of strings holding your student names:

```
...
  for(j = 0; j < 5; j++){
    average = 0;
    for(i = 0; i < 2; i++){
      average += grades[j][i];
    }
    printf("The average mark scored by the student %s is -> %.2f out of 50 \n", student_names[j], average/2);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I had to search how to create an array containing strings for names but it worked. Thanks

Comment: You're welcome - I can't give you ALL the answers ;) glad you figured out the string array.